# Parsing JSON with jQuery .each method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I know this question might appear be too localized but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here is the JSON my method returns:

```
{ "dateTime" : "5/26/2011",
  "requestTime" : 0.1020102,
  "users" : [ { "Email" : "joem@email.com",
        "Location" : "home",
        "Name" : "Joe M",
        "UserId" : "42a7eae4-d4fe-49a3-93df-cd0cf219ac95"
      },
      { "Email" : "test@test.net",
        "Location" : "Work",
        "Name" : "Test Name",
        "UserId" : "97a444fb-6e3d-482c-a966-dbd3e0c739c8"
      }
    ]
}
```

The jQuery I'm using is like so:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Home/GetUsers",
data: dataString,
success: function (data) {                      
     $.each(data.users, function(i, item) {
          $("#results").append('<p>' + item.Name + '</p>');
     });
}
```

I either get undefined, or nothing happens.

I get Object object if I do an alert(data) so I know it's returning something.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which method are you calling to get the data?  You might need to manually convert data into an object.

Comment: Just a RESTful method in asp.net mvc

Comment: I mean which jquery method are you using to make the call?

Comment: Updated with the full .ajax call

Comment: @Jack Marchetti, Show us the action in your Controller called `GetUsers`

Comment: I'm reasonably sure `data` is coming back as a string, trying doing something like `var mydata = $.parseJSON(data)` and alert `mydata`.  You could also specify the `dataType` to be JSON and jQuery will try to convert it for you.

Comment: @Gabe - Why?  I'm showing you what the method returns

Comment: @R0M - I tried that and mydata was null.  if i alert(data) it's just Object object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alert(data.users) shows you undefined?
Try adding dataType: 'text', and then do alert(data) and check you're getting the right json :/

This is working for me:

```
var data = { "dateTime" : "5/26/2011",
             "requestTime" : 0.1020102,
             "users" : [ { "Email" : "joem@email.com",
                "Location" : "home",
                "Name" : "Joe M",
                "UserId" : "42a7eae4-d4fe-49a3-93df-cd0cf219ac95"
              },
              { "Email" : "test@test.net",
                "Location" : "Work",
                "Name" : "Test Name",
                "UserId" : "97a444fb-6e3d-482c-a966-dbd3e0c739c8"
              }
            ]
           };
$(data.users).each(function(i, item) {
    $("#results").append('<p>' + item.Name + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: must be something else than because I keep getting undefined when I do an alert(data.users).

Comment: After setting dataType: 'text', do alert() to data (not data.users), so you can see the full result.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try doing something like this:

```
$.post('Home/GetUsers', dataString, function(result) {
  $(result.users).each(function(i, item){
            $('#results').append('<p>'+item.Name+'</p>');
            });
  },'json'
});
```